# How to control overflow line spacing for text within nested <p><a>

Tags: html, css

How can I minimize the spacing between the following overflow text of this button that is simply a

with a nested

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pkCDd)**

```
<style type="text/css">
  p.button:hover { cursor: pointer; }
  p.padding  { padding:0; margin:0;}
</style>
<div style="width: 370px">
<table class="inline_button" style="width: auto ">
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;  min-height: 28px;background-color: #000000; line-height: 28px;font-size: 12px;font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;padding: 0;border: 2px solid #fe9d39;"><div id="whatever">
            <p class="button padding" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold;"><a style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold; padding:0px 10px; display:block;" href="http:msn.comr}">when this is really long it eventually overruns but can figure out </a></p>
        </div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: not sure what you mean but I guess you may want to look for the so-called `line-height`, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKIix

Comment: Adjust the line-height:28px; to any small value like 18px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly set `line-height` property for `<a>` or `<p>` to `normal` or `1` or in `px` unit.

add this code

`p.padding a{line-height:normal;}`

OR

`p.padding a{line-height:1;}`

OR

`p.padding a{line-height:12px;}`

to your stylesheet.